# Input layer is incompatible even when dimensions (apparently) match

Tags: machine-learning, keras, python-3.x

I am making a sequential neural network for classification, with 3 dense layers, which will be trained on a simple synthetic dataset. The description of dataset is as follows:

- Data and class labels are integers. They are 2000 each.
- There is only a single feature column (populated by np.arange(2000) * 3)
- There is only a single label which indicates last digit of number (populated by np.arange(2000) *3 % 10).

After making the model, I am encountering the following error when calling model.fit():

> ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential is incompatible with the
> layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 1500 but received
> input with shape (100, 1)

I have uploaded the commented Jupyter Notebook for this code on Google Collab: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/14v92NTBxIEIFJh2BhybfqhawHYIBvKnm?usp=sharing

Any suggestion about how to fix this error and get reasonable accuracy on training set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You set the input shape to `(1500, 2)` whereas your data only contains a single feature. You should therefore change the shape to `(1,)` or `(None, 1)` to match the shape of the input data.

Comment: It works! Thanks for the answer. Can you explain why does `(None, 1)` also work?

Comment: @hhj8i `(1,)` and `(None,1)` are identical in this case

Comment: `None` can stand for any number, in this case the number of samples in a single batch.

Comment: I was also wondering that the feature and label columns in training data, have 1500 values each. But an array with shape `(1, )` can contain a single value only. So will the training be accurate when using `input_shape = (1, )`? So far, I am getting 9% accuracy on training data.